# Python parsing table data into an array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, parsing

Firstly I am using python 2.7.

What I am trying to achieve is to separate table data from a active directory lookup into "Firstname Lastname" items in an array, which I can later compare to a different array and see which users in the list do not match.

I run `dsquery group domainroot -name groupname | dsget group -members | dsget user -fn -ln` which outputs a list as such:

> ```
>   fn               ln               
>   Peter            Brill            
>   Cliff            Lach          
>   Michael          Tsu               
>   Ashraf           Shah             
>   Greg             Coultas          
>   Yi               Li               
>   Brad             Black            
>   Kevin            Schulte          
>   Raymond          Masters (Admin)  
>   James            Rapp            
>   Allison          Wurst            
>   Benjamin         Hammel            
>   Edgar            Cuevas           
>   Vlad             Dorovic (Admin)        
>   Will             Wang                        
> dsget succeeded
> ```

Notice this list has both spaces before and after each data set.

The code I am using currently:

```
userarray = []
p = Popen(["cmd.exe"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
p.stdin.write("dsquery group domainroot -name groupname | dsget group -members | dsget user -fn -ln\n")
p.stdin.write("exit\n")
processStdout = p.stdout.read().replace("\r\n", "").strip("")[266:]
cutWhitespace = ' '.join(processStdout.split()).split("dsget")[0]
processSplit = re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', cutWhitespace)
userarray.append(processSplit)
print userarray
```

My problem is that when I split on the blank space and attempt to re-group them into "Firstname Lastname" when it hits the line in the list that has (Admin) the grouping gets thrown off because there is a third field. Here is a sample of what I mean:

```
['Brad ', 'Black ', 'Kevin ', 'Schulte ', 'Raymond ', 'Masters (', 'Admin) ', 'James ', 'Rapp ', 'Allison ', 'Wurst ',
```

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to group this better or correctly. Thanks!

Comment: a fast work around is to remove whitespace next to a parenthesis in a line, then split, then re group. but njzk2s answer is better!

Comment: Looks like the lines can be parsed by position. Use slicing to get the first 20 characters, left and right trim, then grab everything past 20 and left and right trim it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# the whole file.
content = p.stdout.read()
# each line as a single string
lines = content.split()
# lets drop the header and the last line
lines = lines[1:-1]
# Notice how the last name starts at col 19
names = [(line[:19].strip(), line[19:].strip()) for line in lines]
print(names)
=> [('Peter', 'Brill'), ('Cliff', 'Lach'), ('Michael', 'Tsu'), ('Ashraf', 'Shah'), ('Greg', 'Coultas'), ('Yi', 'Li'), ('Brad', 'Black'), ('Kevin', 'Schulte'), ('Raymond', 'Masters (Admin)'), ('James', 'Rapp'), ('Allison', 'Wurst'), ('Benjamin', 'Hammel'), ('Edgar', 'Cuevas'), ('Vlad', 'Dorovic (Admin)'), ('Will', 'Wang')]
```

Now, if the column size change, just do `index = lines[0].indexof('ln')` before dropping the header and use that instead of 19

Comment: I needed to change the line to `lines = content.split("\r\n")` to parse the data into `('Firstname', 'Lastname')

Comment: stdout should also have a `readlines()` method, so `lines = p.stdout.readlines()` should work too

Answer (score 0):

`split` has a `maxsplit` argument you so you can tell it to split only the first separator, so you could say:

```
cutWhitespace = ' '.join(processStdout.split(None,1)).split("dsget")[0]
```

on your sixth line to tell it to split no more than once.